# Nativescript 8 Screen freeze after splash screen is loaded in release build

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

Guys I'm working on one of my own projects, and I'm using

> nativescript 8.2.1 along with angular 13.2.0

I had some weird issue that is when we run the project using the following command

> "ns run android"

application getting compiled and running on emulator fine.

[image]

but if I build to production and run it on an emulator I can only see a blank screen or white screen, here is the command used for that

> "ns run android --clean --release --key-store-path "PATH/my-release-key.keystore" --key-store-password myPass --key-store-alias myAlias --key-store-alias-password myPass"

this is screenshot
[image]

This is what my root route looks like, redirection to home route is not working. but I tested if I add a button to app.component.html then I can see that button on the emulator screen. but routing is not working
[image]

This issue is caused when we only build with --release command otherwise debug mode it's working fine.

need your help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending multiple days of debugging, I finally, figure out the reason why the production build screen is getting frozen.

> **This is happening due to Firebase**

I configure the firebase to my app referring through Nativescript version 8 documentation, here is the configuration that I have did
https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/firebase-firestore.html

> **npm install @nativescript/firebase-firestore**

```
//importing firebase modules
import { firebase } from "@nativescript/firebase-core";
import "@nativescript/firebase-firestore";

//Initialize firebase as per nativescript documentation
await firebase().initializeApp();
```

in debug mode, this is working fine without any issue, but the production release builds it's not working.

**For resolve this issue. I used a different firebase package.**
here is the documentation link https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

if you are NativeScript 7+:

> **tns plugin add @nativescript/firebase**

for NativeScript 6:

> **tns plugin add nativescript-plugin-firebase**

Thanks..